# How can I append bytes of data in an already uploaded file in StorJ?

Tags: go, upload, append, reader

I was getting segment error while uploading a large file.

I have read the file data in chunks of bytes using the Read method through io.Reader. Now, I need to upload the bytes of data continuously into the StorJ.

Comment: Please expand, and show us some code, without code one cannot guess,  you cannot express the mistake you are making, because you don't know where it is.

Comment: storj.ConnectUpload(ctx, bucket, fileData, file, fileNamesDEBUG, storjConfig, err)
I am using this function to upload the bytes into a file. But, the file is getting overwritten everytime a new buffer comes in, I need to append the data into the file.

Answer (score 1):

Storj, architected as an S3-compatible distributed object storage system, does not allow changing objects once uploaded. Basically, you can delete or overwrite, but you can't append.

You could make something that *seemed* like it supported append, however, using Storj as the backend. For example, by appending an ordinal number to your object's path, and incrementing it each time you want to add to it. When you want to download the whole thing, you would iterate over all the parts and fetch them all. Or if you only want to seek to a particular offset, you could calculate which part that offset would be in, and download from there.

```
sj://bucket/my/object.name/000
sj://bucket/my/object.name/001
sj://bucket/my/object.name/002
sj://bucket/my/object.name/003
sj://bucket/my/object.name/004
sj://bucket/my/object.name/005
```

Of course, this leaves unsolved the problem of what to do when multiple clients are trying to append to your "file" at the same time. Without some sort of extra coordination layer, they would sometimes end up overwriting each other's objects.